# Highcharts Compare Date Ranges Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would think this would have been a fairly common thing to do but I can't find examples anywhere. I want to compare 3 series of data for 2 different date ranges and see them next to each other in a bar chart. Its easier to understand by the picture: [image: desired end result]

Unfortunately, the only thing I can think of is to add a HIDDEN series and then do my legend in html outside of the highchart. Please tell me there is a better way to do this. This is what I have come up with as an example.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Safe Places To Visit'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Survey Count',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Recommend',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Recommend W/ Comp',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Dont Recommend',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }, {
            name: 'HIDDEN',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Recommend',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Recommend W/ Comp',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Dont Recommend',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    });
});
```

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mfy4uq5n/).

Comment: Have you tried to change hidden series type to 'area' ? It will remain in the legend, but won't take up space in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer here :

- [Grouping Legends in
  Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926516/grouping-legends-in-highcharts)
- [How to get multiple data series into
  Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109742/how-to-get-multiple-data-series-into-highcharts)